# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I am getting the follwing error, Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. how can i uniquely grab the correct ID from this statment

```
function data () {
if($at = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['id'])){$at = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['id']);

$arg = func_get_args();
unset($arg[0]);
$fields = '`'.implode('`,`', $arg).'`';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `list` LEFT JOIN fruits ON location.id =  
fruits.fid     
LEFT JOIN store ON store.id = location.catid WHERE location.link = '$at'")or die(mysql_error());
$query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$query_row = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($query_row==0){
return false;
}else{
foreach ($arg as $field){
$arg[$field] = $query_result[$field];
}return $arg;
}
}
}
```

Comment: There's a problem in your mysql query. What does $fields contain?

Answer (score 1):

```
$fields = '`list`.'.implode('`, `list`.`', $arg).'`';
```

But I strongly recommend [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/in-ten-quick-steps.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem in your mysql query. Specifying the name of the table along with the name of your field would be the easiest solution I guess:

```
$fields = 'tablename'.$fields;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns that it is easier to just change the name of one the id in the table.